# How can i download many csv file dynamically automatic from other website to localhost in my pc in php

Tags: php, csv

I have many .csv file in website, Basically i want to know how can i automatic download this file dynamically. In localhost has download folder, In download folder will be download and save auto without mouse/keyboard touch and then i want to do auto import from download folder without mouse/keyboard touch.

Real Fact is , in that website every day will keep .csv file. But everyday software will be auto download and import in MySQL Database without mouse/keyboard touch.

How can i solve it, please detail mention. Really i will be very happy if i get solution to this problem.

Comment: use php curl to do this

Answer (score 0):

Use the following PHP page in your localhost server:

csvsaver.php:

```
<?php

    $saveLocation = 'files';
    $urls = array(
        'http://yourwebsite/folder/hello.csv',
        'http://yourwebsite/csv1.csv'
    );

    $now = date('Y-m-d_H-i');
    $dir = 'files' . '/' . $now;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($urls); $i++){
        $url = $urls[$i];
        $file = $i . '_' . substr($url, strrpos($url,'/')+1 );
        $path = $dir . '/' . $file;

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        if (!is_dir($dir)) mkdir($dir);
        file_put_contents($path, $data);
    }
?>
```

If for example you put that in 'c:/wamp/www/csvSaver/csvsaver.php', you will also need to create a directory 'files' in it: c:/wamp/www/csvSaver/files/

When you run the above page, it will for example save the two files into:

- c:/wamp/www/csvSaver/2013-02-27_09-45/0_hello.csv
- c:/wamp/www/csvSaver/2013-02-27_09-45/1_csv1.csv

All you need to do is set up something to run the PHP page daily. If you're using linux, set up a cron job. If you're using windows, set up a scheduled task that runs a .bat file. For an example, [Look here.](http://www.abestweb.com/forums/programming-datafeeds-tools-188/connect-site-windows-scheduled-task-49121.html). If that looks too complicated, then just go to your PHP page manually each day.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jodes, In your Coding it will be copy empty file but data don't come. Basically i also went more update that when i will give URL then all .csv file will be downloaded in this url. For example "www.xyz.com/xyz/". Next time when i will execute again this code then .css file will be downloaded which don't download ago.